# PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser not working

Tags: php

Here is a sample that is provided on the Simple HTML DOM Parser website. I threw in an echo statement up top to see if anything even works.

The echo statement prints out, but nothing else does. If I put the echo statement underneath the `file_get_html` statement, it doesn't return anything in the echo statement.

Edit: I get this error in the console:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500
>   (Internal Server Error)

It refers to the file that I'm running this code from, which is odd, because the echo statement prints successfully.

The location of the simple_html_dom.php file is in the same directory as the php file I am running these commands from. Any ideas what I'm missing?

```
<?php
include('simple_html_dom.php');

echo "test";

// Create DOM from URL or file
$html = file_get_html('http://www.google.com/');

// Find all images 
foreach($html->find('img') as $element) 
       echo $element->src . '<br>';

// Find all links 
foreach($html->find('a') as $element) 
       echo $element->href . '<br>';
?>
```

EDIT: I have narrowed the issue down by including enabling php error output.

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function file_get_html() in 
sites.php on line 8
```

It looks like the HTML DOM Parser file isn't loading correctly?

Comment: Is the html properly read? Are you able to print it?

Comment: What does your error log show?

Comment: @RichardSt-Cyr It looks like the html is not being loaded at all, it prints out nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It ended up being a permissions issue with the simple_html_dom.php file - the permissions were set to 'none' for some reason.